# JSONRPC error on sendSignedTransaction

Tags: web3js, transactions, metamask, raw-transaction, ganache

I run ganache, truffle and metmask. If I run the code below I get an error on the this.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction() function:

EDIT: changed my code to the following.. Error remained the same though.

```
    const encoded_tx = this.contract.methods.createCountry("NL", 100, 100, 100000000, this.account).encodeABI();
    const nonce = await this.web3.eth.getBlockTransactionCount(this.account);
    const rawTx = {
        nonce: this.utils.toHex(nonce), 
        gasLimit: this.utils.toHex(3000000),
        gasPrice: this.utils.toHex(this.utils.toWei('20', 'gwei')),
        data: encoded_tx,
        from: this.account,
        to: this.contractAddress
    };

    let tx = new Tx(rawTx);
    tx.sign(this.pvtKey);

    let serializedTx = tx.serialize();
    this.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
    .on('receipt', console.log);
```

The error is the following:

```
index.js:2178 Error: Returned error: {"id":6,"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32603}}
at Object.ErrorResponse (errors.js:29)
```

I have absolutely no idea where to look anymore and feel like I've tried everything, might it have anything to do with the fact that I'm connected to metamask?  When I try to send this transaction through metamask with eth.method.send() the transaction does not give an error and behaves as expected.

Comment: One way to investigate this is to open [Ganache Core source code](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/tree/develop/lib) and search for `-32603` (or more precisely, the hexadecimal representation of `2^32 - 32603`).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but this does not seem to get any hits: https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=-32603&type=

Comment: After doing some research I found out that the error code only means that it's an internal json-rpc error, which isn't helpful at all.

Comment: It is. I don't use ganache, but I assume you have to open specific librairies no? Check if RPC allows the connection to use the librairies you use (web3, web3.eth, etc)

Comment: I think Ganache might not support sendSignedTransaction yet.. I've created an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the nonce you have to call [`web3.eth.getTransactionCount`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactioncount), and not `getBlockTransactionCount`.

- getTransactionCount

  > Get the numbers of transactions sent from this address.
- getBlockTransactionCount

  > Returns the number of transaction in a given block.

To debug interactions with ganache you can start with `ganache-cli --verbose` it will show the interactions between the client an ganache and show more details about transactions.

Comment: wow, I can't believe that was it. Thank you so much!