# send transaction and handling events in web3 1.0

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have created a contract which has a function like this:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value, bytes _data) internal returns (bool) {
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value, _data);
    return true;
}
```

but now when I want to test contract in web3 1.0.0 using following code:

```
var balance = await baxToken.methods.balanceOf(user1).call({from:owner, gas:gasEstimate})
console.log(balance)

await baxToken.methods.transfer(user1, 50000).send({from:owner, gas:gasEstimate}).on('event', console.log)

var balance = await baxToken.methods.balanceOf(user1).call({from:owner, gas:gasEstimate})
console.log('balance')
```

while the first 2 lines of code works however the code stops then. I realized that if I comment the emit Transfer(...) from my contract it works fine.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/48750/how-to-sign-a-send-method-in-web3-1-0/48765#48765 this might help you

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I get nothing. No error no result. The code seems to be stopped working.